# How to get selenium to stay open for a few seconds before closing?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to see what Chrome is displaying at the end of the function. So I'd like to make Selenium stay open for 5 or 10 seconds so I can see where it ended up.

What are my options?

Comment: If this is just for "dev testing"  why not just put a simple sleep to your function before exit. `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`

Comment: @pagep That'll work. Thanks!

Comment: Put a page break on the last line of the script. Then you can have the browser as long as you want. Or you could just comment out the close and quit browser lines.

Comment: @JeffC I don't have close/quit lines. I think because Selenium is being ran from nunit, that it's automatically closed. What is the code for a page break?

Comment: You should take screenshots for every steps to see what exactly happened in every steps instead. Thanks

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?  If so set a debugger breakpoint. If not than pagep gave you an answer.

Comment: I put page break...I don't know why I said that. I meant to say breakpoint. How to do this will depend on the IDE you are using. You'll have to look that up in your IDE docs.

Comment: @JeffC It seems breakpoints don't work with nunit. Visual Studio.